# Easiest way to limit JOIN to only select TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join, left-join

I am using the following query for the main level of a procedure with two nested queries.

The query works and selects the correct data, my only issue is that I would only need the `TOP 1` record from the `JOIN` based on an `ORDER BY modTime desc`.

I found a few posts on this on Google with very different approaches and was not sure which one is the right one here. Example source: [How do I limit a LEFT JOIN to the 1st result in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375436/how-do-i-limit-a-left-join-to-the-1st-result-in-sql-server)

I like the way of wrapping an Inner Join in the Left Join but wasn't sure if that makes sense and how to apply it here. What would be the easiest approach and how to apply this here?

My SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MOC_FetchMenu]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      A.itemID,
                COALESCE(A.parentID, '999999'),
                A.itemName,
                A.linkRef,
                A.sortID,
                COUNT(*) OVER() AS volume,
                D.lastUpdate,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), D.modTime, 106) AS modTime,
                D.modBy,
                '---' AS levelSub,
                (
                  -- begin of my nested queries
                )
    FROM        MOC_Links A
    LEFT JOIN   MOC_Log D
    ON          D.itemID = A.itemID
    WHERE       A.parentID = '1'
    ORDER BY    A.itemName
    FOR XML PATH('level1'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')

END
```

Comment: Just do a subquery with TOP 1 and JOIN on that

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but then got the error I can only have one subquery. How would that work with my other nested queries ?

Comment: Show how you tried it,your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: A subquery with top 1 won't work, he wants 1 row returned per JOIN, not just 1 row.

Comment: What is the table you are trying to get the TOP 1 out of? MOC_Links, MOC_Log, or a totally different table? If it's a different table what is the join column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Cross Apply or Outer Apply

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    MOC_Links A
        OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT TOP 1 *
         FROM   MOC_Log AS D
         WHERE  D.itemID = A.itemID
         ORDER BY D.modTime DESC) D
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works great ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
select top A.itemID,
COALESCE(A.parentID, '999999'),
A.itemName,
A.linkRef,
A.sortID,
COUNT(*) OVER() AS volume,
D.lastUpdate,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), D.modTime, 106) AS modTime,
D.modBy,
'---' AS levelSub,(select top 1 ColumnName from Table)  FROM        MOC_Links A
LEFT JOIN   MOC_Log D
ON          D.itemID = A.itemID
WHERE       A.parentID = '1'
ORDER BY    A.itemName
FOR XML PATH('level1'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```