# Doctrine query get only the "first" of many related (doing join & select to avoid N+1)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In this situation I have 3 related entities
`profile` --OneToMany--> `annualReports` --ManyToOne--> `photo`

And in a loop, for a table I am checking for the existence of the photo in twig like this

```
{% set is_photo = profile.annualReports.toArray()[0].photo.id is defined %}
```

So, a `profile` can have a lot of `annualReports` - this paticular situation I want the very first "report" only.

The question is how do I do this in the `QueryBuilder`? That is join the "first Report" ("first" can be based on minimum id or createdAt date)

UPDATE:
I guess the question is how can I 'LIMIT 1' and specify a sort?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. But for your last part, sorting is done by using `->orderBy()`.

To have better twig, use `profile.annualReports.first`

Comment: sorry, the orderBy needs to be applied to the joining table.  it's 1 object, profile, and joined to it is the "first" of many reports.

Comment: like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161438/select-first-record-in-a-one-to-many-relation-using-left-join but in doctrine/symfony

Comment: also you can add a condition in previus foreach instead of define a variable, check https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first report in twig, you simply need to use the method `first` of the Collection class :

```
{% if profile.annualReports IS NOT EMPTY %}
   {% set report = profile.annualReports.first %}
{% endif%}
```

and to manage the order you must use the doctrine annotation ' @OrderBy ': 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
 * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
private $groups;
```