# Select first record with join from 1:1 to 1:n relation - postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to join two tables in postgresql with the following structure, which is the relation between some areas and some points surrounding it

**Table 1 "d_hid_t"**

```
id_rank | dem_hid_m3s
   1          3.6
   2          3.45
   3          3.40
   4          2.35
   5          2.33
```

**Table 2 "disph"**

```
id_rank |   disph_m3s
   1          0.058
   1          1.36
   1          1833.4
   2          0.017
   2          208.69
   3          0.39
   3          40.79
  ...          ...
```

I'm expecting to get the join output based on the maximum value found for the unique ID of table 1, without repeating the other related values, for example

**Table 3 "output"**

```
id_rank |   disph_m3s
   1          1833.4
   2          208.69
   3           40.69     
  ...          ...
```

So far I followed some instruction on this stack overflow post [Select first record in a One-to-Many relation using left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161438/select-first-record-in-a-one-to-many-relation-using-left-join) but with no success. I keep getting the error "aggregate functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions".
Right now my code looks like this:

```
SELECT a.id_rank, a.dem_hid_m3s, a.geom, b.id_disp, b.dist_km, b.disph_m3s
FROM d_hid_t as a
LEFT JOIN disph as b 
ON a.id_rank = b.id_rank
AND (SELECT max(b.disph_m3s) WHERE a.dem_hid_m3s <= b.disph_m3s)
```

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simply method uses `distinct on`.  I might use it *before* joining:

```
SELECT h.*, d.*
FROM d_hid_t h LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (d.id_rank) d.*
      FROM disph d
      ORDER BY d.id_rank, disph_m3s DESC
     ) d
     USING (id_rank);
```

Note the use of *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.