# Inner Join, only return 1 row for each product

Tags: sql

Hopefully this is something simple but what i am trying to do is only pull back 1 row for each product in the CartContents table. The problem i have is some products have multiple images so and these are being returned if there is more than 1 image linked to a product.

This is what i created however it still pulls back multiple rows for each product.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (pri.FileName), p.Title, tc.Quantity, tc.FK_ProductID
    FROM [Ordering].[CartContents] tc
    INNER JOIN [Ordering].[Products] p ON p.ProductID = tc.FK_ProductID
    INNER JOIN [Ordering].[ProductImages] pri on pri.FK_ProductID = p.ProductID
    WHERE FK_UserID = @FK_UserID
```

Thanks

Comment: What DB engine? And if only 1 row per product - which one?

Comment: Do you want both images returned in a single row or just the first image?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row the same thing is explained quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"in" would get rid of the problem, assuming you didn't have the filename:

```
SELECT p.Title, tc.Quantity, tc.FK_ProductID
FROM [Ordering].[CartContents] tc  INNER JOIN
     [Ordering].[Products] p
     ON p.ProductID = tc.FK_ProductID
where p.ProductID in (select pri.FK_ProductID 
                      from [Ordering].[ProductImages] pri
                     ) and
      FK_UserID = @FK_UserID
```

With the filename, you have to choose one arbitarily:

```
SELECT min(pri.FileName) as FileName, Title, tc.Quantity, tc.FK_ProductID
FROM [Ordering].[CartContents] tc  INNER JOIN
     [Ordering].[Products] p
     ON p.ProductID = tc.FK_ProductID INNER JOIN
     [Ordering].[ProductImages] pri on pri.FK_ProductID = p.ProductID
where FK_UserID = @FK_UserID 
group by Title, tc.Quantity, tc.FK_ProductID
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, This is perfect