# Linking Two Rows of Data Based on Date Out/In

Tags: sql-server, fifo

**Schema and Example Data**

Below is some sample data to show the table layout.  In this example, I only show transactions for a specific ITEM and SERIAL.  In production, however, there will be other ITEMS/SERIALS, so any joins performed will need to be on those two fields.

```
transid Item                        qty Transdate               Type    Serial  IssuedTo
======= =========================== === ======================= ======= ======= ========
423371  SUNNENBOREGAGE1.18-2.0-3    1   2012-10-22 08:49:18.000 ISSRT   G-02145 742
422415  SUNNENBOREGAGE1.18-2.0-3    -1  2012-10-17 18:42:08.000 RETN    G-02145 139
422082  SUNNENBOREGAGE1.18-2.0-3    1   2012-10-17 13:21:38.000 REISS   G-02145 139
421518  SUNNENBOREGAGE1.18-2.0-3    1   2012-10-15 13:37:08.000 ISSRT   G-02145 709
421459  SUNNENBOREGAGE1.18-2.0-3    -1  2012-10-15 09:37:41.000 RETN    G-02145 640
421426  SUNNENBOREGAGE1.18-2.0-3    1   2012-10-15 08:02:19.000 ISSRT   G-02145 640
420100  SUNNENBOREGAGE1.18-2.0-3    -1  2012-10-10 06:23:34.000 RETN    G-02145 742
420097  SUNNENBOREGAGE1.18-2.0-3    1   2012-10-10 06:22:21.000 ISSRT   G-02145 742
```

All returns are marked by either a type of RETN or REISS.  All issues are marked by either a type of ISSRT or REISS.  Reissues (REISS) are both a return and an issue.  The ISSUEDTO field marks who received the item for a REISS or ISSRT transaction.

**Desired Result**

In short, I want to find all returns within a date range (quarter) and the matching issue transaction (regardless of when it was issued) so that I can identify the employee it was issued to and the length (in days) of how long that employee had that specific item/serial.

My final result set would have the columns like the following:

```
ITEM SERIAL EMPLOYEE ISSUETRANSID ISSUEDATE RETURNTRANSID RETURNDATE DAYSOUT
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this since a REISS is technically two transactions on one row and making sure that each ISSRT (or REISS) transaction is only used once for each RETN (or REISS) transaction.  This also sounds a lot like a FIFO/LIFO problem as well, but I can't seem to apply the logic here (which may just be my own shortcoming).

Any help or pointers would be most appreciated!  Thank you =)

Comment: By including the actual business design along with the technical question, you made the post too long and hard to follow or understand, therefore you will get little or no answers. Try simplifying the question to pure technical terms of what you're trying to achieve (for example, linking data in multiple records based on start/end dates, etc...). You could also include a simpler generic example that is easy to follow. You'll get much better responses.

Comment: @JKarthik: ISSRT is an ISSue of a ReTurnable item

Comment: @SamAnwar: Thank you, I will try to shorten my question up.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, I believe I found the answer to my question.  Using the information from the following post was what I needed.

[SQL Server: How to Join to first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row)

My code (which is specific and may not match my example data explicitly):

```
SELECT 
    ReturnedItems.SerialID AS SerialID,
    ReturnedItems.Item AS R_Item,
    ReturnedItems.TransNumber AS R_TransNumber,
    ReturnedItems.TransDate AS R_TransDate,
    ReturnedItems.TypeDescription AS R_TransDescription,
    ReturnedItems.IssuedTo AS R_IssuedTo,
    IssuedItems.TransNumber AS I_TransNumber,
    IssuedItems.TransDate AS I_TransDate,
    IssuedItems.TypeDescription AS I_TransDescription,
    IssuedItems.IssuedTo AS I_IssuedTo,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, IssuedItems.TransDate, ReturnedItems.TransDate) / 24 AS Days_Out
FROM 
    CribMaster.dbo.TRANS AS ReturnedItems CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.Item AS Item,
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.SerialID AS SerialID,
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.TransNumber AS TransNumber,
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.TransDate AS TransDate,
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.TypeDescription AS TypeDescription,
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.IssuedTo AS IssuedTo
        FROM 
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS 
        WHERE
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.SerialID = ReturnedItems.SerialID AND 
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.TypeDescription IN ('ISSRT', 'REISS') AND 
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.TransDate < ReturnedItems.TransDate
        ORDER BY 
            CribMaster.dbo.TRANS.TransDate DESC
    ) AS IssuedItems
WHERE 
    ReturnedItems.TypeDescription IN ('RETN', 'REISS') AND 
    ReturnedItems.TransDate < '10/1/2012' AND
    ReturnedItems.TransDate >= '7/1/2012'
```