# Issue with DISTINCT in my mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i am trying to make a website where i want a photo album.

Thing is that this site will have 2 tables, 1 table that stores name of photo album (`TBLalbum`) and a unique id for that album (`id`,`albumname`).
The second table (`TBLphotos`) stores information about uploaded photos and to what album each photo belongs(`albumid`,`photoname` and some more columns).
Now i want to list all album names which is not so hard to do, but also in same sql query i want it to show the first photo in each album.

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT albumid 
FROM TBLphotos INNER JOIN TBLalbum 
ON TBLalbum.id=TBLphotos.albumid
```

this does not give me the possibility to print out the column `photoname`

and if i include it like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT albumid,photoname 
FROM TBLphotos INNER JOIN TBLalbum 
ON TBLalbum.id=TBLphotos.albumid
```

then it doesn't get `distinct` on just `albumid`.

A bit hard for me to explain, but can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: I tried this to:"SELECT DISTINCT TBLalbum.id,TBLalbum.namn FROM TBLalbum LEFT JOIN TBLphotos ON TBLphotos.albumid=TBLalbum.id" and this works but i allso want to print the column photoname from TBLphotos without making it  repeat the album name. How?

Comment: Possible duplicate, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row

Comment: What do you want it to output in the `TBLalbum.id` column when there is more than one `TBLphotos.photoname`? If you just want it to show the album's id once and then any repeated rows would be null, then that is not something that you do in a database. That is something you will need to do in your presentation end like PHP, or wherever you are consuming the resultset.

Comment: There is no such thing like `DISTINCT` on a single column. What values do you expect to get on the other columns?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT
  a.albumid,
  a.albumname,
  (SELECT photoname FROM TBLphotos p WHERE p.albumid = a.id LIMIT 1) AS photoname
FROM TBLalbum a
```

The subquery limits the result set for each album to just one record with the `LIMIT` clause.  If you want a specific record from `TBLphotos`, you can amend the subquery to put things in a certain order or do whatever you need to do.

Note that `DISTINCT` is for filtering out duplicate rows, which is not (I think)  what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering, i started myself to belive i needed a subquery, sounds like this is the way doing this, but i still not had this to work, i can imagine i need replace "TOP 1" with "LIMIT 1" though i use mysql but there is still something that makes it not work.. i will try figure out, but if you can do it faster i am glad :)

Comment: @OskarOskarsson Oops, I usually work in TSQL, forgot to convert that to MySQL for you.  Just a sec.

Comment: Thanks allot!  now it works perfect like i want it. I really need try to understand the sql language better, where, why and how to use alias and so on. But this helped me for this time. Thanks once again!

Comment: @OskarOskarsson you need to use aliases for tables when you use the same table two or more times in a query (to solve ambiguities). Other than that, I frequently use one or two-letter aliases to have shorter names for the tables involved in the query. When the query uses a field name that appears in two or more tables you need to specify the owning table and a two-letter alias is shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Ok thanks for information, i have not had to use 2 tables at same query before so thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The correct query for your request is:

```
SELECT a.albumid, f.photoname 
FROM TBLalbum a
    INNER JOIN TBLphotos f          # "f" from "first" photo
      ON f.albumid = a.id           #          of this album
    LEFT JOIN TBLphotos o           # "o" from "other" photo
      ON o.albumid = f.albumid      #          of the same album
      AND o.photoid < f.photoid     # "o" is before "f"
WHERE o.photoid IS NULL             # no such "o" exists
```

#### Explanation

This query joins table `TBLalbum` (aliased as `a` from "album") with `TBLphotos` (aliased as `f` from "first photo of this album"). Because of the `INNER JOIN`, the albums without photos will **not** be included. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead if you want them included.

Next, it joins the table `TBLalbum` again (aliased as `o` from "other photo"). The first join condition (`o.albumid = f.albumid`) ensures the photos selected from `o` are in the same album as their matches from `f`. The second condition (`o.photoid < f.photoid`) pairs a row from `f`<sup>1</sup> only with the rows from `o` having a smaller `photoid` (i.e. created earlier). 
Replace this with your own definition of *earlier* in order to get the *first* photo as expected.

Because the second `JOIN` is a `LEFT JOIN`, it will add to the result set all the rows from `f`<sup>1</sup>, including those that does not have any match in `o` because there is no photo in `o` that is *earlier* than the photo currently selected from `f`. For these rows, a row full of `NULL`s is used instead of the missing row from `o`.

The `WHERE` clause filters from the result set produced by the joins only the pairs (`a`, `f`, `o`) that have `NULL` values in `o.photoid`; i.e. when no "other photo" in the same album was found in `o` as being *earlier* than a certain photo from `f`. These are the *first* photos of each album you expect.

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup> The `LEFT JOIN` combines the tables `a` and `f` already joined (left) with table `o` (right). The result set will contain all the combinations of rows produced by the `INNER JOIN` of `a` and `f`, at least once (and not all the rows from `f` as said above; I preferred to write it this way to make it simpler).

<sup>2</sup> I assumed there is a field named `photoid` in table `TBLphotos` and it is the `PK` of the table (it's important to have distinct values). If you change the sorting criterion to define the *first* photo from the table (for example, using the upload time) and the field you use does not have distinct values then on tie the query returns all the photos having the same smallest value for the chosen column. You can fix this easily by keeping/adding into the `ON` clause the condition that uses `photoid` (or other field that could solve the tie).

<sup>3</sup> You can put whatever fields you want/need into the `SELECT` clause but only from tables `a` and `f`. Nothing stops you to put fields from `o` but all of them are `NULL`. Read the entire explanation again if you didn't understand why.

<sup>4</sup> If you want to understand how this query works then remove the `WHERE` clause, run it using a MySQL client and analyze the result set.

<sup>5</sup> You'll find a lot of answers to similar questions on SO tagged [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group). If they use `GROUP BY` avoid them because they are wrong and not conformant with the SQL standard (most of them work by accident). If they use sub-queries (with or without `GROUP BY` in the inner query) they are probably correct but most of the time they are slow. Sub-queries are difficult to optimize, and a lot of times it is not even possible. If they use MySQL variables then they are also slow. I don't know why MySQL variables are slow, I guess it's because the query planner cannot make the best use of indexes in this case.

Comment: Thanks for taking allot of time writing this and to help, Paul Griffin made it work and i am sure allso your example works good, i am happy for both of your fast response and i am impressed. Thanks allot!

Comment: @OskarOskarsson I would commend this answer to you.  I am not 100% convinced that it is faster than mine, but it is far more flexible in how you can shape your data.

Comment: @PaulGriffin I think your query can be optimized by MySQL query optimizer. Its processing is very similar with the one of an `INNER JOIN` that has the `LIMIT` applied earlier.

Comment: Ok thanks again, i will try both of your querys i just had a litte hurry to get it work and get online, but now i want to take time and try understand both this querys and what they do. Thanks again to you both.