# How to left join to first row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

How to left join two tables, selecting from second table only the first row? 
[image: first match]

My question is a follow up of:
[SQL Server: How to Join to first row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2043259)
I used the query suggested in that thread.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  id INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO table1(id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO table1(id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO table1(id) VALUES (3);
GO

CREATE TABLE table2(
  id INT NOT NULL
, category VARCHAR(1)
);
INSERT INTO table2(id,category) VALUES (1,'A');
INSERT INTO table2(id,category) VALUES (1,'B');
INSERT INTO table2(id,category) VALUES (1,'C');
INSERT INTO table2(id,category) VALUES (3,'X');
INSERT INTO table2(id,category) VALUES (3,'Y');
GO

------------------
SELECT 
table1.* 
,FirstMatch.category
FROM table1

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
    table2.id
    ,table2.category   
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table1.id = table2.id
    ORDER BY id
    )
    AS FirstMatch
```

However, with this query, I get inner join results. I want to get left join results. The tabel1.id in desired results should have '2' with NULL. How to do it?

Comment: change CROSS APPLY to OUTER APPLY

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Why, you big rep people, drop answers in comments, not in answers? Then small rep people like me could mark it as accepted for sake of other users. Thanks, works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment of [t-clausen.dk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/806969/t-clausen-dk) this does the job:

change `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY`

Answer (score 4):

use `row_number` and `left join`

```
with cte as(

select id,
       category,
       row_number() over(partition by id order by category) rn
       from table2
)
select t.id, cte.category
from table1 t
left outer join cte 
on t.id=cte.id and cte.rn=1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id  category
1   A
2   (null)
3   X
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20b4a/3)

Comment: Nop, it does not produce desired results. Check it yourself.

Comment: I just seen the pictures in question, let me to review it again

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin please check it again how do you say it doesn't gives correct result, there was a missed comma which is corrected please check it again and give a feedback

Comment: you're welcome, also there is some points that you have to notice if you want to use a simple subquery, I actually wanted to write it but because I the points I decided to write this version.

Answer (score 3):

```
select table1.id, 
(SELECT TOP 1 category FROM table2 WHERE table2.id=table1.id ORDER BY category ASC) AS category
FROM table1
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment bro. But adding an "IF" after a "NO" doesn't make any sense at all ;)

Comment: This selects arbitrary category, is it what OP expected?

Comment: the OP did not mentioned if 'category' is in sequence or random? so y are everyone assuming?

Comment: @VincentPzc actually he did, in the logic of his code

Comment: Yes, produces desired results! Thank you for that answer because the query is simple and short. What are the drawbacks of that method? What does it mean that it selects arbitrary category?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    table1.id ,table2.category 
FROM table1 Left join table2
on table1.id = table2.id
where table2.category = ( select top 1 category  from table2 t where table1.id = t.id) 
OR table2.category is NULL
```

Comment: Goal achieved with this method, too. Thanks.

Comment: a cryptic solution with no guarantee of getting the category with the lowest ID. If there are duplicate categories in table 2, this may return a different number of rows for some categories

Comment: joining on a varchar when you have an integer available is not good practice either

Comment: I have joined on integer only . the category check is in the Where clause. Wouldn't it be too much to worry about the data which we don't know at this point (Speculative generality) . There can be a lot of different data condition we can think of . but I think this satisfies the problem statement.

Comment: you are getting several different categories and comparing them in a where clause. That is a join. It is certainly possible to make a join in the where clause. And yes, you should worry about data you don't know. Writing the script correct for future data should always be a priority