# sqlite, order by date/integer in joined table

Tags: sqlite, join, inner-join

I have two tables

Names

```
id | name
---------
5  | bill
15 | bob
10 | nancy
```

Entries

```
id | name_id | added    | description
----------------------------------
2  | 5       | 20140908 | i added this
4  | 5       | 20140910 | added later on
9  | 10      | 20140908 | i also added this
1  | 15      | 20140805 | added early on
6  | 5       | 20141015 | late to the party
```

I'd like to order `Names` by the first of the numerically-lowest `added` values in the `Entries` table, and display the rows from both tables ordered by the `added` column overall, so the results will be something like:

```
names.id | names.name | entries.added | entries.description
-----------------------------------------------------------
15       | bob        | 20140805      | added early on
5        | bill       | 20140908      | i added this
10       | nancy      | 20140908      | i also added this
```

I looked into joins on the first item (e.g. [SQL Server: How to Join to first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row)) but wasn't able to get it to work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT n.id, n.name, e.added, e.description 
FROM Names n INNER JOIN
     (SELECT name_id, description, Min(added) FROM Entries GROUP BY name_id, description) e
     ON n.id = e.name_id 
ORDER BY e.added
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this query a try:

```
SELECT Names.id, Names.name, Entries.added, Entries.description 
FROM Names 
INNER JOIN Entries 
ON Names.id = Entries.name_id 
ORDER BY Entries.added
```

Add `DESC` if you want it in reverse order i.e.: `ORDER BY Entries.added DESC`.

Comment: No, because this lists Names multiple times if there are multiple Entries.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` will help... ;)