# Join two tables and such that only one row from 2nd table is joined

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have Two tables, MachineWiseMaterial (Fields: McMatID) and MaterialIssueRegister (Fields: McMatID, IssueDate, IssueTime, EMR).
I want the last issue date, time and EMR for each McMatID.

I can find the same for any individual McMatID using SELECT TOP 1 as follows.

```
SELECT TOP 1 McMatID, IssueDate, IssueTime, EMR 
FROM MaterialIssueRegister 
WHERE McMatID = [some value, eg. 1] 
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC, IssueTime DESC, EMR DESC;
```

But when I'm trying to join both tables, I'm not getting desired results.

```
SELECT MachineWiseMaterial.McMatID, b.IssueDate, b.EMR 
FROM MachineWiseMaterial 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 McMatID, IssueDate, IssueTime, EMR 
FROM MaterialIssueRegister  
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC, IssueTime DESC, EMR DESC) AS b
ON MachineWiseMaterial.McMatID = b.McMatID;
```

The above query returns only those McMatID whose IssueDate are Max and not the max date for each McMatID.

Comment: I dont know the syntax of SQL in access, but im pretty your probleme is that your are not using `GROUP BY McMatId`   to group all the id and then take the Max date of each. Actually `(SELECT TOP 1 McMatID, IssueDate, IssueTime, EMR 
FROM MaterialIssueRegister  
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC, IssueTime DESC, EMR DESC) AS b` will always contain only 1 id because you only select the Top 1, no matters how much different id there are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: How to Join to first row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row)

Comment: @Matriac Thanks for the answer. I realised my mistake just after posting and forgot about this post for ever. I never used this account there after. Really Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this..

```
SELECT MachineWiseMaterial.McMatID, b.IssueDate, b.EMR 
FROM MachineWiseMaterial m1
where m1.McMatId=(SELECT TOP 1 McMatID
FROM MaterialIssueRegister  m2
where m2.McMatId=m1.McMatId
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC, IssueTime DESC, EMR DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this:

select MachineWiseMaterial.McMatID, b.EMR , max(b.IssueDate)
FROM MachineWiseMaterial 
LEFT JOIN MaterialIssueRegister b
ON MachineWiseMaterial.McMatID = b.McMatID
group by MachineWiseMaterial.McMatID, b.EMR

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realised my mistake just after posting and forgot about this post for ever. I never used this account there after. Really Sorry for that.