# sql - retrieve only first record using join

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables: Employee, Contact, Employee_Contact

**Employee:**

```
EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME...
```

**CONTACT:**

```
CONTACT_ID, TELEPHONE, MOBILE...
```

**EMPLOYEE_CONTACT:**

```
EMP_ID, CONTACT_ID
```

Employee and Contact table is mapped with Employee_Contact table.
So I want to retrieve all Employees with Employee's only first contact, I tried this query but it is retrieving all the contacts related to that employee. Please check below query and let me know in case of any mistakes.

```
SELECT EMP.FirstName
    ,DEPT.Description AS Department
    ,CNT.Mobile
    ,CNT.Telephone
FROM MstEmp EMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department DEPT ON EMP.DeptID = DEPT.Department_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_Contact EC ON EMP.EMP_ID = EC.EMP_ID
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM Contact CONT
    WHERE EC.Contact_ID = CONT.Contact_ID
    ) CNT
```

[image: Check this image for query output]

Comment: ROWNUMBER() OVER partition will do that job

Answer (score 0):

Use Top keyword retrieve top one record.

```
SELECT TOP 1 EMP.FirstName, DEPT.Description AS Department, CNT.Mobile, 
CNT.Telephone
FROM MstEmp EMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department DEPT on EMP.DeptID = DEPT.Department_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_Contact EC ON EMP.EMP_ID = EC.EMP_ID
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Contact CONT WHERE EC.Contact_ID = 
CONT.Contact_ID)CNT
```

Comment: I tried this but it is retrieving only first employee, I want all employees with only first contact

Comment: You can add contact as well in the join rt? and pick the top one

Comment: Tried it, still it is retrieving only first employee

Comment: Please check thus link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT EMP.FirstName
    ,DEPT.Description AS Department
    ,t.Mobile
    ,t.Telephone
FROM MstEmp EMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department DEPT ON EMP.DeptID = DEPT.Department_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_Contact EC ON EMP.EMP_ID = EC.EMP_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact CONT ON EC.Contact_ID = (
        SELECT MIN(c.Contact_ID) c_id
        FROM Contact c
        WHERE CONT.Contact_ID = c.Contact_ID
        ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and get the first record for all the employees and then join it with the other tables.

```
SELECT EMP.FirstName,
       DEPT.Description AS Department,
       c.Mobile,
       c.Telephone
FROM MstEmp EMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department DEPT ON EMP.DeptID = DEPT.Department_ID
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY EMP_ID) AS RN
             FROM Employee_Contact  ) EC ON EMP.EMP_ID = EC.EMP_ID
INNER JOIN Contact c ON c.Contact_ID=EC.Contact_ID
WHERE EC.RN=1
```

Comment: It is giving my an error "The multi-part identifier "EMP.EMP_ID" could not be bound." anyway, thank you :)

Comment: @ShreyasPednekar Updated my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
select * from (
select E.[emp_id],
       E.[first_name], 
       E.[last_name], 
       C.*, 
       RANK() over (partition by (E.[emp_id], E.[first_name], E.[last_name]) order by (select null)) [RN]
from Employee [E]
join employee_contact [EC] on E.[emp_id] = EC.[emp_id]
join contact [C] on EC.[contact_id] = C.[contact_id]
) A where RN = 1
```

Comment: It is giving an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'by'."

Comment: @ShreyasPednekar Try now

Comment: @ShreyasPednekar How about now?