# How to build a view without repeating ids?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I have three tables that I want to join together and create a view as a lookup. The problem is is that I am getting duplicate `provider id` because the `provider_name` is different.

Table1

```
provider_id  provider_name
545          Kent Hospital
```

Table2

```
provider_id  provider_name
565          Devin Hospital
```

table 3

```
provider_id  provider_name
545          Kent Medical Center
```

I am getting :

```
provider_id  provider_name
545          Kent Hospital
545          Kent Medical Center
565          Devin Hospital
```

final expected result:

```
provider_id  provider_name
545          Kent Hospital
565          Devin Hospital
```

Realistically, it doesn't matter which name is used since they are usually almost the same.

But the problem is that I am getting duplicates in `provider_id` and that's leading into duplicate records on my joins to other tables. I know there are ways to avoid this on the joins to the end-point tables using approaches like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row), but to me this seems like a bandage rather than a solution at the core.

my current approach:

```
--CREATE VIEW lookup_providers AS 
SELECT DISTINCT provider_id, provider_name
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT provider_id, provider_name
FROM table2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT provider_id, provider_name
FROM table3
```

Sample tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (provider_id nvarchar(30), provider_name nvarchar(30))
CREATE TABLE table2 (provider_id nvarchar(30), provider_name nvarchar(30))
CREATE TABLE table3 (provider_id nvarchar(30), provider_name nvarchar(30))

INSERT INTO table1 (provider_id, provider_name) VALUES ('545','Kent Hospital')
INSERT INTO table2 (provider_id, provider_name) VALUES ('565','Devin Hospital')
INSERT INTO table3 (provider_id, provider_name) VALUES ('545','Kent Medical Center')
```

Comment: You need to decide what to do when the same provider_id appears in two different tables.  There is no DWIM command in sql.

Comment: not related to the answer, however using DISTINCT and UNION in the same query is just redundand. Leave either UNION (preferable) or DISTINCT statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the name, then use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT provider_id, MIN(provider_name) as provier_name
FROM ((SELECT provider_id, provider_name
       FROM table1
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT provider_id, provider_name
       FROM table2
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT provider_id, provider_name
       FROM table3
      )
     ) tt
GROUP BY provider_id;
```

There are more elaborate mechanisms if you want to choose a particular name -- the longest, the shortest, prioritizes by a table.  But you specify that an arbitrary name is fine, so `MIN()` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A slight guess, but i'd assume you're after something like:

```
CREATE VIEW lookup_providers AS

    WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT provider_id, provider_name
        FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT provider_id, provider_name
        FROM table2
        UNION
        SELECT provider_id, provider_name
        FROM table3),
    RNs AS(
        SELECT provider_id, provider_name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY provider_id ORDER BY provider_name) AS RN
        FROM CTE)
    SELECT provider_id, provider_name
    FROM RNs
    WHERE RN = 1;

GO
```