# How to join only last record of the table in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two tables `beneficiaries` and `accommodation_histories` and I want only to join last record of `accommodation_histories` into `beneficiaries`.

This is my method so far:

```
public function getQuery(): Builder
{
    return DB::table('beneficiaries')
        ->select([
            'beneficiaries.id',
            'media.id as media',
            'beneficiaries.name as beneficiary_name',
            'beneficiaries.surname',
            'beneficiaries.gender',
            'beneficiaries.date_of_birth',
            'countries.name as country_of_birth',
            'accommodation_histories.center as center',
            'accommodation_histories.date_of_receipt as date_of_receipt',
            'accommodation_histories.release_date as release_date',
        ])
        ->leftJoin('media', 'media.model_id', '=', 'beneficiaries.id')
        ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'beneficiaries.country_of_birth')
        ->join('accommodation_histories', 'accommodation_histories.beneficiary', '=', 'beneficiaries.id');
}
```

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row

Comment: There is an example in the documentation under [Subquery Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins) which may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below at the parent model (beneficiaries) :

```
public function accommodation_histories()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Accommodation_histories')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: But I must use query, not eloquent