# Symfony Doctrine Querybuilder - Select only first row of ordered join in one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's say I have entities `User` and `Comment` in a one-to-many relationship. Assume the relationship is set up correctly in the models and is called `comments` on the `User` model. Let's say `Comment` has a field `text` that is the text written in the comment.

Each `Comment` belongs to one `User`, but each `User` may have any number of comments (including no comments at all.)

I'm using Doctrine-ORM 2.7. I need to select `User` data and only the `text` of their most recent comment if it exists. I'm really struggling to piece together how to do this. My thoughts so far:

- The query should `leftJoin()` the `User` with `Comment` table on the user ID. I think I want a `LEFT JOIN` since that way users without any comments are still selected.
- The Comments part needs to be a nested query that does something like `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` on the comments that have that user ID, so that only the most recent one is selected.
- I don't think I can use `groupBy()` since I need to select the `text` of the most recent comment, but I could probably get the `MAX(comment.id)` through here and that might come in handy?

My progress on an attempt so far:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository(User::class)
         ->createQueryBuilder('u')
         ->select('u.id, u.username') // ...etc. user data
         ->addSelect('c.text') // comment text
         ->leftJoin('u.comments', 'c', 'WITH', ....) // Place nested subquery here somehow?
         ->getQuery()
         ->getArrayResult();
```

I feel like the nested query has to be something like this:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository(Comment::class)
         ->createQueryBuilder('c')
         ->select('c.id')
         ->where('c.user', ':user')
         ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
         ->getQuery()
         ->getScalarResult();
```

This is a made-up example; in the real application, **optimization is a concern** so I'd like to minimize the number of nested queries executed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049441/6111743) seems to have a good raw SQL approach, but I'm getting confused on how to translate that to query builder syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your first 2 bullet items show that you understand SQL.  "Confused on how to translate that to query builder syntax" says that the framework is in the way.

Comment: Good point; I will remove the 'mysql' tag from my question. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked whether you can apply [Criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) collection filtering for it? Seems like a good approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have what you are looking for, but I think I was just facing a similar problem.

Here is the query I came up with:

```
        $users = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.id')
        ->addSelect('c.id AS c_id', 'c.text')
        ->join('u.pub', 'c')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

You would still need to filter for the latest comment.

It worked for my purpose, although it gave a response, that looked like this:

```
        "id": 1,
    "c_id": 1,
    "text": "...",
```

instead of this:

```
        "id": 1,
    "c": {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "..."
}
```

but that wasn't really a problem.

Edit 1: Just tried using it with one to many and it returns a whole user object for every comment they have.
Still going to leave the awnser here, could be useful somehow.

Edit 2: Or you could maybe use a DTO (data transfer object)? Or is that going to be too slow for your needs?