# Using TOP 1 (or CROSS APPLY) within multiple joins

Tags: sql

I've reviewed multiple Q&A involving TOP 1 and CROSS APPLY (including the very informative [2043259](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/how-to-join-to-first-row)), but I still can't figure out how to solve my issue. If I had a single join I'd be fine, but fitting TOP 1 into the middle of a chain of joins has stumped me.

I have four tables and one of the tables contains multiple matches when joining due to a previous bug (since fixed) that created new records in the table instead of updating existing records. In all cases, where there are multiple records, it is the top-most record that I want to use in one of my joins. I don't have access to the table to clean up the extraneous data, so I just have to deal with it.

The purpose of my query is to return a list of all "Buildings" managed by a particular person (user choses a person's name and they get back a list of all buildings managed by that person). My tables are:

Building (a list of all buildings):

```
BuildingId  BuildingName
1           Oak Tree Lane
2           Lighthoue Court
3           Fairview Lane
4           Starview Heights
```

WebBuildingMapping (mapping of BuidingId from Building table, that is part of an old system,  and corresponding WebBuildingId in another piece of software):

```
BuildingId  WebBuildingId
1           201
2           202
3           203
4           204
```

WebBuildingContacts (list of ContactID for the building manager of each building). This is the table with duplicate values - where I want to choose the TOP 1. In sample data below, there are two references to WebBuidingId = 203 (row 3 & row 5) - I only want to use row 3 data in my join.

```
Id  WebBuildingId   ContactId
1   201             1301
2   202             1301
3   203             1303
4   204             1302
5   203             1302
```

Contacts (list of ContactIds and corresponding property manager Names)

```
ContactId   FullName
1301        John
1302        Mike
1303        Judy
```

As noted, in the example above, the table WebBuildingContact has two entries for the building with a WebBuidingId = 203 (row 3 and row 5). In my query, I want to select the top one (row 3).

My original query for a list of buildings managed by 'Mike' is:

```
SELECT BuildingName
FROM Building bu 
JOIN WebBuildingMapping wbm ON wbm.BuildingId = bu.BuildingId
JOIN WebBuildingContact wbc ON wbc.WebBuildingId = wbm.WebBuildingId
JOIN Contacts co ON co.ContactId = wbc.ContactId
WHERE co.FullName = 'Mike'
```

This returns 'Fairview Lane' and 'Starview Heights'; however, Judy manages 'Fairview Lane' (she's the top entry in the WebBuildingContacts table).  To modify the query and eliminate row 5 in WebBuildingContacts from the join, I did the following:

```
SELECT BuildingName
FROM Building bu 
JOIN WebBuildingMapping wbm ON wbm.BuildingId = bu.BuildingId
JOIN WebBuildingContact wbc ON wbc.WebBuildingId = 
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 WebBuildingId
    FROM WebBuildingContact
    WHERE WebBuildingContact.WebBuildingId = wbm.WebBuildingId
    )
JOIN Contacts co ON co.ContactId = wbc.ContactId
WHERE co.FullName = 'Mike'
```

When I try this; however, I get the same result set (ie it returns 'Mike' as manager for 2 buildings). I've also made various attempts to use CROSS APPLY but I just end up with 'The multi-part identifier could not be bound', which is a whole other rabbit hole to go down.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT bu2.BuildingName
FROM building bu2
WHERE bu2.BuildingId IN 
    (SELECT MAX(bu.BuildingId)
    FROM Building bu 
    JOIN WebBuildingMapping wbm ON wbm.BuildingId = bu.BuildingId
    JOIN WebBuildingContact wbc ON wbc.WebBuildingId = wbm.WebBuildingId
    JOIN Contacts co ON co.ContactId = wbc.ContactId
    WHERE co.FullName = 'Mike'
    );
```

Comment: Thank you Yenny - that worked great! Just to help my learning, if anyone has a way that this can be done using either TOP 1 or CROSS APPLY I'd still be interested in seeing it.